# How to send form data to the server using React and Node JS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I'm using the redux toolkit to handle a reactjs login form. I receive a 404 server error when I submit the form.
The Login API i created checks if the user exists before returning a 404 error if it doesn't exists.
When I submit the form I get a 404 error and when I console log the data sent, it appears that the form sent no data at all.
I looked at my form code and believe I made a mistake, but I am at a loss.

**Here is what my code looks like:**

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { loginFailure, loginStart, loginSuccess } from "../../redux/userSlice";
import axios from 'axios';


const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const form = useRef();

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    const LoginData = {
      email: email,
      password: password
    }
    setLoading(true);
    dispatch(loginStart());
    console.log(LoginData)
    axios
      .post(
        `auth/login`,
        LoginData
      )
      .then((res) => {
        setLoading(false);
        dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoading(false);
      dispatch(loginFailure);
      });
      return false;
  };

  return (
    <div id="app" className="app">
      <div className="login login-v1">
        <div className="login-container">
          <div className="login-body">
            <div className="login-content fs-13px">
              <form
                ref={form}
                onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                className="form-horizontal"
              >
                <div className="form-floating mb-20px">
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    className="form-control fs-13px h-45px"
                    id="emailAddress"
                    placeholder="Email Address"
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    {...register("email", { required: true })}
                  />
                  {errors.email && (
                    <ul
                      className="parsley-errors-list filled"
                      id="parsley-id-7"
                      aria-hidden="false"
                    >
                      <li className="parsley-required">
                        Email is required.
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  )}
                  <label
                    htmlFor="emailAddress"
                    className="d-flex align-items-center py-0"
                  >
                    Email Address
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-floating mb-20px">
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    className="form-control fs-13px h-45px"
                    id="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    {...register("password", { required: true })}
                  />
                  {errors.password && (
                    <ul
                      className="parsley-errors-list filled"
                      id="parsley-id-7"
                      aria-hidden="false"
                    >
                      <li className="parsley-required">
                        Email is required.
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  )}
                  <label
                    htmlFor="password"
                    className="d-flex align-items-center py-0"
                  >
                    Password
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div className="login-buttons">
                  <button
                  type="submit"
                    className="btn h-45px btn-success d-block w-100 btn-lg"
                    
                  >
                  {loading ? "Login in..." : "Log me in"}
                    
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**Server API:**

```
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) return next(createError(404, "User not found!"));

    const isCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!isCorrect) return next(createError(400, "Wrong credentials"));

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT);
    const { password, permissions, ...others } = user._doc;
    res
      .cookie("access_token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
      })
      .status(200)
      .json(others);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

**Router:**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const authController = require("../controllers/authController")

//SIGN IN
router.post('/login', authController.login)

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: 404 means that `url` you provide to `axios.post()` is incorrect. This problem should be solved first, then request and response must be examined and fixed is necessary.

Comment: The URL provided is correct. The 404 error comes from the login api that checks if the user exists.
if (!user) return next(createError(404, "User not found!"));

The problem is when I submit the form I get an empty object {email: "", password:""}

Comment: Do your state values `email` and `password` really get filled? What's the `console.log(LoginData)` output?

Comment: when I console.log(LoginData)  I get {email: "", password:""}

Comment: It means that you treat inputs in wrong way. Actually you have a mix of pure HTML form, `useForm` and state, and it looks like chaos. First  try to change email input and add `value` prop:`onChange={(e) => {
console.log('email value', e.target.value);
 setEmail(e.target.value)}}
value={email}`, this will make your input controlled and for sure will partially solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I will try and see. Hopefully will solve the issue

Comment: Second problem is that you are trying use `react-hook-form` but send state values and misuse `react-hook-form`. You don't need any refs and state. Read examples carefully, they and quite simple and don't use what you don't need to.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: Yes, the probelem is solved. Thank you

Comment: Can you please help me answering this question?     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74770283/how-to-redirect-user-to-dashboard-after-authentication-in-react-js