# How to redirect user to dashboard after authentication in react js?

Tags: reactjs, formik, redux-toolkit

Im using react js with redux/toolkit to create user authentication.
I created a form with Formik. When the I submit the form it doesn't redirect me to the dashboard aand I'm unable to identify the issue.

I created a  default authentication service under src/services/AuthService.js, the service method works coresponded useAuth fuction.

AuthService.js

```
export async function apiSignIn (data) {
    return ApiService.fetchData({
        url: '/v1/auth/login',
        method: 'post',
        data
    })
}
```

And then I created a store with to Slices:

1- sessionsSlice

2- userSlice:

The logic I implemented in : src/store/auth/sessionSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const sessionSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth/session',
    initialState: {
        token: '',
        signedIn: false,
    },
    reducers: {
        onSignInSuccess: (state, action) => {
            state.signedIn = true
            state.token = action.payload
        },
        onSignOutSuccess: (state) => {
            state.signedIn = false
            state.token = ''
        },
        setToken: (state, action) =>  {
            state.token = action.payload
        }
    },
})

export const { onSignInSuccess, onSignOutSuccess, setToken } = sessionSlice.actions
export default sessionSlice.reducer
```

The logic I implemented in : src/store/auth/userSlice .js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const initialState = {
    avatar: '',
    userName: '',
    email: '',
    authority: []
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth/user',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setUser: (_, action) => action.payload,
        userLoggedOut: () => initialState,
    },
})

export const { setUser } = userSlice.actions
export default userSlice.reducer
```

The signIn logic implementation in the useAuth looks this way:

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { setUser, initialState } from 'store/auth/userSlice'
import { apiSignIn, apiSignOut, apiSignUp } from 'services/AuthService'
import { onSignInSuccess, onSignOutSuccess } from 'store/auth/sessionSlice'
import { REDIRECT_URL_KEY } from 'constants/app.constant'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import useQuery from './useQuery'

function useAuth() {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const query = useQuery()
    const { token, signedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.auth.session)
    const signIn = async (values) => {
        try {
            const resp = await apiSignIn(values)
            if (resp.data) {
                const { token } = resp.data
                dispatch(onSignInSuccess(token))
                if(resp.data) {
                    dispatch(setUser(resp.data || { 
                        avatar: '', 
                        userName: resp.data.userName, 
                        authority: [resp.data.role], 
                        email: resp.data.email
                    }))
                }
                const redirectUrl = query.get(REDIRECT_URL_KEY)
                
                navigate(redirectUrl ? redirectUrl : '/dashboard')
                return {
                    status: 'success',
                    message: ''
                }
            }
        } catch (errors) {
            return {
                status: 'failed',
                message: errors?.response?.data?.message || errors.toString()
            }
    }
    }

    const signUp = async (values) => {
        try {
        const resp = await apiSignUp(values)
            if (resp.data) {
                const { token } = resp.data
                dispatch(onSignInSuccess(token))
                if(resp.data.user) {
                    dispatch(setUser(resp.data.user || { 
                        avatar: '', 
                        userName: 'Anonymous', 
                        authority: ['USER'], 
                        email: ''
                    }))
                }
                const redirectUrl = query.get(REDIRECT_URL_KEY)
                navigate(redirectUrl ? redirectUrl : '/dashboard')
                return {
                    status: 'success',
                    message: ''
                }
            }
        } catch (errors) {
            return {
                status: 'failed',
                message: errors?.response?.data?.message || errors.toString()
            }
    }
    }

    const handleSignOut = ()  => {
        dispatch(onSignOutSuccess())
        dispatch(setUser(initialState))
        navigate('/dashboard')
    }

    const signOut = async () => {
        await apiSignOut()
        handleSignOut()
    }
    
    return {
        authenticated: token && signedIn,
        signIn,
        signUp,
        signOut
    }
}

export default useAuth
```

And finally, My form looks this way:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Input, Button, Checkbox, FormItem, FormContainer, Alert } from 'components/ui'
import { PasswordInput, ActionLink } from 'components/shared'
import useTimeOutMessage from 'utils/hooks/useTimeOutMessage'
import { Field, Form, Formik } from 'formik'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import useAuth from 'utils/hooks/useAuth'

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    userName: Yup.string().required('Please enter your username'),
    password: Yup.string().required('Please enter your password'),
    rememberMe: Yup.bool()
})

const SignInForm = props => {

    const { 
        disableSubmit = false, 
        className, 
    } = props

    const [message, setMessage] = useTimeOutMessage()

    const { signIn } = useAuth()

    const onSignIn = async (values, setSubmitting) => {
        const { userName, password } = values
        setSubmitting(true)
        
        const result = await signIn({ userName, password })

        if (result.status === 'failed') {
            setMessage(result.message)
        }
        setSubmitting(false)
    }

    return (
        <div className={className}>
            {message && <Alert className="mb-4" type="danger" showIcon>{message}</Alert>}
            <Formik
                initialValues={{
                    userName: '', 
                    password: '', 
                    rememberMe: true 
                }}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}
                onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                    if(!disableSubmit) {
                        onSignIn(values, setSubmitting)
                    } else {
                        setSubmitting(false)
                    }
                }}
            >
                {({touched, errors, isSubmitting}) => (
                    <Form>
                        <FormContainer>
                            <FormItem
                                label="User Name"
                                invalid={errors.userName && touched.userName}
                                errorMessage={errors.userName}
                            >
                                <Field 
                                    type="text" 
                                    autoComplete="off" 
                                    name="userName" 
                                    placeholder="User Name" 
                                    component={Input} 
                                />
                            </FormItem>
                            <FormItem
                                label="Password"
                                invalid={errors.password && touched.password}
                                errorMessage={errors.password}
                            >
                                <Field
                                    autoComplete="off" 
                                    name="password" 
                                    placeholder="Password" 
                                    component={PasswordInput} 
                                />
                            </FormItem>
                            <div className="flex justify-between mb-6">
                                <Field className="mb-0" name="rememberMe" component={Checkbox} children="Remember Me" />
                            </div>
                            <Button block loading={isSubmitting} variant="solid" type="submit">
                                { isSubmitting ? 'Signing in...' : 'Sign In' }
                            </Button>
                        </FormContainer>
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SignInForm
```

Comment: Do you reach `const redirectUrl = query.get(REDIRECT_URL_KEY)` and what's in `redirectUrl`?

Comment: redirectUrl is a query param. Example (sign-in?redirectUrl=/home or sign-in?redirectUrl=/sales) where there is an attempt to reach unauthorized route from the user so when the user log in successfully get redirected to the page specified in redirectUrl query param.

Comment: I meant exact value of `redirectUrl`.

Comment: There is no exact value of redirectUrl.

Comment: const redirectUrl = query.get(REDIRECT_URL_KEY)
                
                navigate(redirectUrl ? redirectUrl : '/dashboard'

Comment: There is a check condition of redirectUrl. As you can see.

Comment: I see, but what's `console.log(redirectUrl)` result? Any other messages/warnings/errors in console?

Comment: console.log(redirectUrl) if there is query param it gets it value (Ex: dashboard) if not is return empty ('')

Comment: Maybe this is a problem - an empty value or path without `/` which are not recognized by router ?

Comment: It's not a problem because its working in the demo template with default auth. 
The issue started when I changed the default auth api endpoint with my own.

Comment: The problem solved. It was an issue from the backend. The useAuth.js hook needs a token and I forgot to send it along with the user data.

Thank you for your help